# How to convert Mapbox's Expression.get()'s result into a color suitable for fillColor()?

Tags: mapbox-android

The following code doesn't seem to apply the value of `fillColorProp` from my JSON file

***JSON content***

```
"fillColorProp": "#FF0000"
```

***Java***

```
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.fillColor;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression.get;
// ...
FillLayer fillLayer = new FillLayer("abc123", source.getId()).withProperties(
                fillColor(get("fillColorProp"))
        );
```

I tried to get convert the type of the property a few different ways but couldn't find a syntax that would compile:

```
fillColor(color(literal(get("fillColorProp"))));
fillColor(Color.parseColor(literal(get("fillColorProp"))));
```

How do I properly convert Mapbox's Android `Expression.get()`'s result into a color suitable for passing as an argument to `PropertyFactory.fillColor()`, `PropertyFactory.lineColor()`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

[Expression.toColor()](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.1.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/expressions/Expression.html#toColor-com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression-) seems to work:

```
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.fillColor;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression.get;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.expressions.Expression.toColor;
// ...
fillColor(toColor(get("fillColor")))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for my case